# Read the string value from BufferedWriter object

Tags: java, spring

I have BufferedWriter object passed from outside my project. I need to check the value that has been stored in BufferedWriter writer object. And I need to do it in the middle of my code process just to add some extra value based on the logic/condition that comes. I tried to find if it is possible to add get the string value that I added in BufferedWriter. But didn't know how to read the String inside the object. For example:

```
public int writeValue(BufferedWriter writer) {
        writer.write("Here is one *");
        writer.write("Here is two *");
        //Now I need to count the * from writer object and need to return the value 2
    }
```

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own implementation of [`java.io.Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) that delegates to `writer` while also keeping track of how many times `'*'` is written.

Comment: If writes are being encapsulated in `writeValue`, what would be the problem with keeping track in the code itself alone?

Comment: @g00se If it's that simple, that would work, but I'm assuming the calls to `write` happen in some function called directly or indirectly by `writeValue`.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense

Comment: @SolomonUcko Ucko, can you please give me one example? I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: @KabirajKharel What did you try? In what way didn't it work?